# gradle not able to detect module

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have a multimodule project. there is 2 modules:
- server module
- domain module

in the build.gradle of the domain module I put :

```
group = 'com.xxx.yyyy.zzz'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

and the server module imports the domain module as follow :

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'com.xxx.yyyy.zzz', name: 'domain', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

...
}
```

howerver he is not able to detect it!
the jar is published to the maven m2 repo and I am able to see it. and i am using mavenLocal to get dependecies from the m2

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I deleted the gradle cache, stopped the gradle daemon without success!

Any idea ?

the build.gradle of the server module:

```
group = 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz', name: 'domaine', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
// other dependecies ......
}
```

the build.gradle of the domain module:

```
group = 'com.desjardins.experiencecredit.gestiondemandes'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: mavenrepo)
        }
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy uploadArchives
```

the settings.gradle of the main project :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'XXX'
include 'server'
include 'domaine'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple modules in the same project, you should instead declare the dependencies using the `project` object:

settings.gradle at root project level

```
rootProject.name = 'my-application'

include 'server'
include 'domain'
```

Then define the build files - root project build.gradle, server module build.gradle and domain module build.gradle.

In the server module's build.gradle, declare the dependency as follows:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':domain')

  ...
}
```

Refer: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/

Comment: could you please share your project structure and build file code

Comment: and there is no reason that I cant read the artifactories as I ve done ... I pubish my jars to the m2 and I read them from the m2

Comment: IMO, multi-module configuration above should work, unless there's something amiss in the configuration. As for your approach, maybe it's a build order issue in multiple modules. So, in the server module's build.gradle, pls try adding `build.dependsOn ":domain:uploadArchives"`

Comment: Do you have a demo application that you can share, probably on github? That would help to debug the issue.